# When will our public beta begin?

Tags: discussion

The private beta is supposed to last 7 days.  It has now been 10 days.  What is keeping us from moving from our private beta to the public beta?

Comment: I meant to ask this myself.

Comment: Me, too!    ........

Comment: Now that our site has launched to public beta, I would like to note somewhere that it says the public beta launched 4 days ago, not today.

Answer (score 4):

Now; we've gone public.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the people who need to push us from private to public were out for the long Holiday weekend. I guess is that we will go to public mode sometime today or tomorrow.